# Why compiler says that argument doesn't implement required traits?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, hyper

I started learning Rust language for a while ago and now I am working on implementing a websocket server for a personal project. With this said, I am not a professional Rust programmer and I am still in the phase of learning the basics.

I develop this project with three libraries, `tokio`, `hyper` and `tokio-tungstenite`. My HTTP server is written in `hyper`. There is basically only one handler. This handler does one thing, upgrades the incoming UPGRADE HTTP requests to WebSocket connections.

```rust
use std::str;

use tokio::io::{AsyncReadExt, AsyncWriteExt};
use tokio::prelude::*;

use hyper::header::{HeaderValue, UPGRADE, SEC_WEBSOCKET_ACCEPT};
use hyper::service::{make_service_fn, service_fn};
use hyper::upgrade::Upgraded;
use hyper::{Body, Client, Request, Response, Server, StatusCode};
use std::net::SocketAddr;

// A simple type alias so as to DRY.
type Result<T> = std::result::Result<T, Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>>;

async fn server_upgrade(req: Request<Body>) -> Result<Response<Body>> {
    let mut res = Response::new(Body::empty());

    // Send a 400 to any request that doesn't have
    // an `Upgrade` header.
    if !req.headers().contains_key(UPGRADE) {
        *res.status_mut() = StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST;
        return Ok(res);
    }

    // Setup a future that will eventually receive the upgraded
    // connection and talk a new protocol, and spawn the future
    // into the runtime.
    //
    // Note: This can't possibly be fulfilled until the 101 response
    // is returned below, so it's better to spawn this future instead
    // waiting for it to complete to then return a response.
    let upgraded: Upgraded = match req.into_body().on_upgrade().await {
      Ok(upgraded) => upgraded,
      Err(e) => {
        eprintln!("upgrade error: {}", e);
        return Err(Box::new(e));
      },
    };
    tokio_tungstenite::accept_async(upgraded);
    Ok(res)
}
```

In the last 3rd line, the compiler emits an error saying these:

```
the trait bound `hyper::upgrade::Upgraded: tokio::io::async_read::AsyncRead` is not satisfied
the trait `tokio::io::async_read::AsyncRead` is not implemented for `hyper::upgrade::Upgraded`

the trait bound `hyper::upgrade::Upgraded: tokio::io::async_write::AsyncWrite` is not satisfied
the trait `tokio::io::async_write::AsyncWrite` is not implemented for `hyper::upgrade::Upgraded`
```

But when I look at the documentation for [hyper::upgrade::Upgraded](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.13.9/hyper/upgrade/struct.Upgraded.html#trait-implementations), I can see that it actually implements those traits. As I also look at the [tokio-tunsgstenite](https://docs.rs/tokio-tungstenite/0.12.0/tokio_tungstenite/fn.accept_async.html)'s documentation, indeed these traits are the same traits from the same crate.

Could an experience rustecean help me how to resolve this issue and convince the compiler that the `upgraded` instance implements the same traits? Maybe a version mismatch among crates?

I am also attaching my `Cargo.toml` file here.

```
[package]
name = "async-rs"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Bora Semiz <Bora Semiz's email address>"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
hyper = "0.13.9"
tokio = { version = "^0.2", features = ["full"] }
tokio-tungstenite = "0.12.0"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hyper is using Tokio version `0.2.x`, while tokio-tungstenite is using Tokio version `0.3.x`. The changelog from Tokio `0.2` to `0.3` included breaking changes to the `AsyncRead` and `AsyncWrite` traits, making the two incompatible with their version `0.2` counterparts.

You can use the [tokio_compat_02](https://crates.io/crates/tokio-compat-02) crate to bridge the two until Hyper release a new version (also upgrade your own `tokio` version to `0.3` in `Cargo.toml`), alternatively downgrade tokio-tungstenite to `0.11.0` which uses tokio `0.2.x` if you prefer.